# Tableviewer validation in WIzardPage

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

In my eclipse rcp application, I use a Wizard in which one of the WizardPage uses a TableViewer component. There are 2 columns in the tableviewer and I have enabled `EditingSupport` for one of the column. My requirement is to validate the values entered in the editable columns so that none should be spaces. Also I need to do the validation only after the user has finished editing all the rows. I tried various approaches. But none seem t be working.

1. I tried finding listeners on the Table element and the Tableviewer element but with no luck(I tried `FocusListener`on the Table and `SelectionChangedListener`on TableViewer)
2. I tried using `canFlipToNextPage()` overriden method of the WizardPage as suggested by one of the articles on the eclipse page but that too seem to be of little help. the problem with this approach is that `canFlipToNextPage()` is called by the platform even before the page is shown
3. I get the same result as #2 when using `getNextPage` overridden method of either the wizard or the wizard page

Could anyone point me to the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to diverge away from your question a little bit and give you some proper MVC hints.

- You shouldn't listen for changes in the actualy rows, but in the model that is represented by that row.
- Models can have property change listeners (for example), and can validate themselves, thus providing APIs such as `isValid()` to the UI.
- On the UI part (the View), you can listen for model changes, and you `setPageComplete(model.isValid());` when an event is caught.
- It is bad practice to have a model for each row (same goes for non-MVC implementations).

Comment: I dont have a model for each row but have a model for one view. I tried and explored few other TableViewer/Table model listeners which did the trick. I used 'TraverseListener' ,'KeyListener'and 'MouseListener' on the 'Table' object .

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can tell that the user has finished editing **all** the rows.

I would validate the table each time the user changes a cell and in the validation call `WizardPage.setPageComplete(boolean)` to enable / disable the Next and Finish buttons.

Comment: I would like to give a final validation report before navigating away from the WizardPage. Thats the reason why I am looking at a way to  say that the user has logically completed his editing

Comment: Another method that could be used is introduce a new SWT Button (labelled "Validate") which would have a 'MouseListener'. and this can validate and set the pagecomplete to true. ButI dont think it would be a good UI experience

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier if you validated your columns "live" and store the result in a flag which is used in **WizardPage#getNexPage()** to determine wether to get the next page or just return the current page (**this**) again along with some illustration of your validation's result?

Comment: I tried and explored few other TableViewer/Table model listeners which did the trick. I used 'TraverseListener' ,'KeyListener'and 'MouseListener' on the 'Table' object . Also I do a live check to ensure that a if a value is not entered after an edit , I disable the next button of the WizardPage